# Paralleling a list in python

Tags: python, threadpool, python-multiprocessing

Let's say I have a list "A" that's fairly large and I want to do work modify each element, and I have a function "f" that I want to use to do that.

I've looked at the multiprocessing library but I have a few questions about it.

I think this is how I'm supposed to call my function f for each thread

```
pool = Pool(num_threads)
pool.map(f,A)
```

Now for a few questions:

1. If I modify A in f will it be changed outside of f?
2. How do I refer to the part of A that is being sectioned off in f?

Answer (score 0):

**If I modify A in f will it be changed outside of f?**
No.  `f` doesn't even have access to `A` - the point of the `map` is to iterate over `A` and pass each element to `f`.  Kind of like:

```
for elem in A:
    f(elem)  # but called in a separate process
```

**How do I refer to the part of A that is being sectioned off in f?**
[The first example in the docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming)  shows how you refer to the part that is being sectioned off (each element of your array).  Your function, `f` should take a parameter that will be assigned an element of the array `A`.

You may want to look at either [pipes or queues](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) for message passing between your main process & the functions running in other processes.  Another good option would be a [manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers).